# Writing array directly to parameter gives error in c++

Tags: c++, templates, reference, constants, function-declaration

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename VAR, unsigned int N>
int size(VAR (&arr)[N])
{
return sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
}

int main()
{
cout << size("Test"); //This is working

int x[] = {7, 5, 43, 8};
cout << endl
     << size(x); //And this works too

cout << endl
     << size({7, 9, 7, 9}); //When i try this its give me "no matching function for call to 'size'" error

return 0;
}
```

Parameter takes strings and arrays that modified outside the parameter. but i need to write the array directly inside the function like the code above. **size({*some integers*});**

Comment: This function already is in the standard library: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size

Comment: g++ version 11.2.0 (GCC) builds it without `error`.

Comment: A *non-const lvalue reference* can not bind to an *rvalue*. Here `size({7, 9, 7, 9})`, the argument `{7, 9, 7, 9}` is an rvalue.

Comment: Unrelated: You could return directly `N` instead of `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])`

Answer (score 6):

Declare the function parameter like

```
int size( const VAR (&arr)[N])
```

That is you may not bind a temporary object with a non-constant lvalue reference.

Answer (score 5):

`{1,2,3,4}` is not an array, but a [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).

Anyhow, don't reinvent the wheel. We already have [`std::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size); for example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::size("Test") << '\n'; //This is working

    int x[] = {7, 5, 43, 8};
    std::cout << std::size(x) << '\n'; //And this works too

    std::cout << std::size({7, 9, 7, 9}) << '\n'; // this too

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Error is because you parameter take address of array(that is **rvalue**) and you give whole array(that is **lvalue** ) that's why code give error .

For solve this you make parameter const

`

```
 #include <iostream>


using namespace std;


 template <typename VAR, unsigned int N>


int size(const VAR (&arr)[N])
   {
 return sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
}

int main()
  {
cout << size("Test"); //This is working

 int x[] = {7, 5, 43, 8};
 cout << endl
 << size(x); //And this works too

 cout << endl
 << size({7, 9, 7, 9}); //When i try this its give me "no matching function for 
 call to 'size'" error

  return 0;
   }`
```

I hope you get Your answer .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Good first answer! But can you clean up the layout a bit?